# Pushing new branch to remote pushing everything again

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, git-push

I created a new branch `develop` from `master`. Then I pushed the new branch to the remote using `git push -u origin develop` from `develop` branch. This command took too much time to push the new `develop` branch. The output is:

```
$ git push -u origin develop
Counting objects: 11531, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6217/6217), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11531/11531), 38.90 MiB | 142.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 11531 (delta 6220), reused 7234 (delta 3876)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for develop:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/scupids/supertext/pull-requests/new?source=develop&t=1
remote: 
To https://knoxxs@bitbucket.org/scupids/supertext.git
 * [new branch]      develop -> develop
Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
$
```

From the output it seems that it pushed everything again. It pushed about `40 MiB` of data.

Just for the reference the origin is hosted on Bitbucket.

Following is the output of the log command:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
* faa7d51 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/develop, master, develop) adds profile data to customer DTO
* 1f562c1 UI/ latest compiled css
* d19ccb0 UI/ Added customer stream and basic styling
.
.
.
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening?

Comment: What did you not understand in this ? Everything being pushed to new branch, the output or the output of the complex log command ?

Comment: I concluded that from the size of the data pushed. Not sure I might be wrong in concluding that. But then why it is pushing that much data?

Comment: Can you explain  why -u option ?

Comment: the size of the data would be all the commits that you have in your other branch. That is the reason of the huge size.

Comment: @rajuGT to make `develop` track `origin/develop`.

@cafebabe1991 Why pushing all the commits of other branch again?

Comment: @knoxxs since both local and remote branch repositories branch name are same. try using without -u option.

Comment: @rajuGT That will not make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Git does not push everything every time.

Possible explanation for this case: you cloned some repository, then changed your local repository's `origin` url to point to another (possibly empty) repository (git doesn't invalidate `remotes/origin/*` branches in this case). Then you pushed, and git found no commits on the other side, so it had to push every commit from `develop`.

I've just tested with Bitbucket HTTPS transport: simple "new branch" `push` transfers about 200 bytes (see the `POST git-receive-pack` line):

```
$ git checkout -b test
Switched to a new branch 'test'

$ git push --verbose -u origin test
Pushing to https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org': 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
POST git-receive-pack (183 bytes)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for test:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/pull-requests/new?source=test&t=1
remote: 
To https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
 * [new branch]      test -> test
Branch test set up to track remote branch test from origin.
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/test'
```

Comment: But my remote master was up to date before I pushed the changes. Also how many commits you had in the parent branch of `develop`

Comment: Are you sure about "remote master was up to date"? I created my branch `test` from `master` (so those two branches point at the same commit); `master` had many, many commits (repo size was about 15 MiB). If you have doubts about my explanation, can you reproduce your issue from scratch (starting with `git clone ...` and ending with `git push --verbose ...`) and show the full log of your actions?

Comment: Yes I am 200% sure about my master was up there, because I pushed all my changes and then made the new branch.

I will try the verbose option.

Comment: @knoxxs So have you tried reproducing this from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the normal behavior of git.

Imagine that someone who is not synced with distant master branch wants to switch on your branch, which is containing some commits from master that he doesn't have yet.

The way that you thought it works would prevent this user from pulling your branch because he doesn't have the missing commits without synchronizing his local master branch.

As your branch tree contains every commits from the beginning, this issue is not happening and the user can pull your branch anyway.

Comment: I am getting your point. Actually today I was first time reading about git workflows and planning to include `feature/topic` branches in my workflow. While reading about workflows I understood that I will be creating a `feature/topic` branch oftenly. This means whenever I will create a new `feature/topic` branch, I have to push the complete commit history again? This is fine for a project like mine which has only about 1k commit but pushing  a new  `feature/topic` branch to a big OS projects (like linux) might take very-very long time. What people do in that case?

Comment: It may take a long time indeed. The best way to work on online branch is to not deleting the branch after the merge, and use this branch to add stuff to the topic feature.

Comment: This is insane. I mean, git definitely should not push commits that already exist on the other side, otherwise every small one-commit push would result in entire branch transfer.

Comment: @Roman is actually right. In the case I explained before, the server would just send to the user the missing commits from the master branch. Sorry I'm tired, was a bad day ^^